# Why do intuitionistic connectives preserve open sets in the topological interpretation of IPC?

Tags: general-topology, logic, intuitionistic-logic

Is there a deeper significance to the fact that the topological intepretation of the connectives of intuitionistic propositional calculus sends open sets to open sets?

---

Let $(\varphi)^*$ refer to the interpretation of $\varphi$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology. According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), we can translate intuitionistic propositional formulas inductively into subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, where tautologies are exactly the expressions with interpertation $\mathbb{R}$.

$$ \begin{align} (\bot)^* & = & \emptyset \\ (\top)^* & = & \mathbb{R} \\
(A \land B)^* & = & A^* \cap B^* \\
(A \lor B)^* & = & A^* \cup B^* \\
(A \to B)^* & = & \text{int}((\mathbb{R} \setminus A^*) \cup B^*)
 \end{align} $$

This is a subset of the topological interpretation of one of the modal logics, I've heard. I'm not such sure which modal logic, but I have heard that one of them has a topological interpretation. I think it's S4 given [this presentation](http://www.rmi.ge/tolo3/Presentations/Lucero-Bryan-Tutorial_1.pdf). To obtain this modal logic, remove the rule for $\to$ and add $(\square A)^* = \text{int}(A^*)$ and $(\lozenge A)^* = \text{cl}(A^*)$ and $(\lnot A)^* = (A^*)^C$.

After thinking about this for a while, one thing that jumped out at me is that the interpretation of each of the connectives *retains the open-set-ness of its arguments*. Let $\star$ be any connective; if $A^*$ and $B^*$ are open, then $(A \star B)^*$ is as well.

Not all of the modal intepretations preserve open sets, in particular, the rules for $\lozenge$ and $\lnot$ send open sets to closed sets, so the connectives of IPC seem somewhat special.

Here are the axioms of a Hilbert system for IPC, from the Wikipedia article. The only inference rule is modus ponens. $\to$ is right-associative. $\land$ and $\lor$ have higher precedence than $\to$.

$$ A \to B \to A \\
(A \to B \to C) \to (A \to B) \to A \to C \\
A \land B \to A \\
A \land B \to B \\
A \to B \to A \land B \\
A \to A \lor B \\
B \to A \lor B \\
(A \to C) \to (B \to C) \to (A \lor B) \to C \\
\bot \to A $$

Comment: I am not sure what kinds of answers you're looking for, or even what the question is. The system of all open sets of a given topological space ordered by inclusion is a complete [Heyting algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Heyting_algebra_semantics). [Kripke semantics for IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Intuitionistic_first-order_logic) is essentially just an Alexandroff space (with specialization order $\leq$).

Comment: The interpretations of $\land$, $\lor$, $\to$ are open maps when "treated as functions of their subexpressions" (I'm not sure exactly how to phrase it), but this isn't true of the interpretation of $\lozenge$ in modal logic. It seemed like an interesting property; I'm wondering if it's just a coincidence.

Comment: Note that the Gödel-Tarski translation, which prefixes $\square$ to every subformula an intuitionistic formula, translates IPC into S4 faithfully. This is easy to see from a sequent calculus presentation (e.g. the one given in Troesltra-SSchwichtenberg's Basic proof theory)

Comment: As for *why* we're interested in that particular Heyting algebra: my view is that it arises naturally from studying the category of sheaves of sets on the topological space, in particular in finding a subobject classifier.  Briefly: if $\mathscr{F}' \subseteq \mathscr{F}$ is a subsheaf, then $\mathscr{F}'$ is uniquely determined by the data of: for each $U$ and each $x \in \mathscr{F}(U)$, there is a maximum open set $V \subseteq U$ such that $x |_V \in \mathscr{F}'(V)$.  That leads to considering the sheaf $\Omega(U) := \{ V \subseteq U \mid V \mathrm{~open} \}$...

Comment: And then the Heyting algebra of open subsets of $X$ is just the global sections of that sheaf of Heyting algebras.

Comment: It might also be helpful to flip the perspective around. You might _want_ to interpret propositions as open sets, for whatever reason. Then negation needs to be tweaked from the 'obvious' definition to actually be open. However, this tweak means that $¬¬A$ is no longer the same as $A$ in general. So you cannot interpret all the rules of classical logic, while intuitionistic logic works.

Comment: @DanDoel I heard something once, years ago, about an analogy between open sets and *semidecidable propositions*, but I don't remember enough of the details to really ask a coherent question about it.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Yes, that is one of the core ideas behind, for example, Paul Taylor's [abstract Stone duality](http://www.paultaylor.eu/ASD/). There is a topology on propositions where open sets correspond to semidecidable checks for truth, and closed sets correspond to semidecidable checks for falsity. And open/closed sets in other spaces can be classified by the membership mapping. So, sets where you can semi-decide membership are open, and those you can semi-decide non-membership are closed.